# Is there a way to merge two git branches without cloning?

Tags: version-control, github, merge, hubot

I am trying to write a tool that will automatically merge code from one branch to other. It will be a command on hubot that will merge the appropriate branches. What I am looking for is a way to do this merge without cloning the code locally. Is there a way to do this? I am using github so a github api will be helpful as well.

Answer (score 1):

The github api gives you the ability to perform a merge directly on github's repo without cloning.

See [the docs](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/merging/).

Answer (score 0):

I didnt understand your requirement completely, however, these are steps i use to merge branch from other repo, see if that helps

```
 git remote add -f (remote name) /path/or/URL/to/remote
 git merge -s ours --no-commit (remote name)/master
 git read-tree --prefix=foo/bar/ -u (remote name)/master
 git commit -m "Merged (remote name) into subdirectory /foo/bar"
```

Thats it.

Comment: I don't think so. My question is about merging branch "a" to branch "b" in a repository "x" without cloning the repostitory "x"